# php cURL return page with error 500 on 000webhost

Tags: php, curl

My page is host at 000webhost.com
following is the scipt running curl:

```
$ch = curl_init($u);
$fp = fopen("u.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

When I open the u.txt on my server, it has the following 500 error message:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /p. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>                                      
</body>
</html>
```

I ran the `phpinfo();` on the server and cURL is enable.

Answer (score 0):

the goal was to download a large html file, the issue has been fixed using following code also found somewhere on stackoverflow:

```
function download($file_source, $file_target) {
$rh = fopen($file_source, 'rb');
$wh = fopen($file_target, 'w+b');
if (!$rh || !$wh) {
    return false;
}

while (!feof($rh)) {
    if (fwrite($wh, fread($rh, 4096)) === FALSE) {
        return false;
    }
    echo ' ';
    flush();
}

fclose($rh);
fclose($wh);

return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your webpage is being run by Jetty - i.e. your PHP code is not actually running.
Stop or uninstall Jetty and then try again.

> ---
>
> *Powered by Jetty://*